# Facing challenges while migration from Spring-security 3.2 to 5.7

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am migration from Spring-security 3.2 to 5.7(due to Spring migration). In 5.7 i am seeing entire encoding repo is removed(import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding). I was using MessageDigestPasswordEncoder(algorithm-MD5). How to achive the same encryption in spring 5.7

I tries using PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder() -> method isPasswordValid;. Earlier it was MessageDigestPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new MessageDigestPasswordEncoder("MD5") -> method matches();. But It is failing at spring context initialisation with following log :
org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 214 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/spring-mvc-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 214; columnNumber: 35; cvc-enumeration-valid: Value 'md5' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration '[bcrypt]'. It must be a value from the enumeration.